# How to set up Spring boot with submodules in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

So I'm just playing (experimenting) with gradle and spring-boot.

When I follow the hello world I easily get the project running which kind of makes me happy.

Now I'd like to have a structured project; For this I'm using Intellij Community (not sure if relevant). I have the following structure.

/Project
 - build.gradle
 - settings.gradle (only includes Services)
/Project/Services/
 - build.gradle
 - settings.gradle (only includes MyService)
/Project/Services/MyServices
 - build.gradle

Now I can share some of my build.gradle files but I"m trying random things I find on the internet. My problem is that the spring boot classes are not available at MyService. The following directory structure inside the Myservice is standard Java (/src/main/java )

I'm trying to put the dependencies & versions in my main build.gradle if possible. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong.

Currently I've only used gradle for simple android development work.

/Project/build.gradle

```
group 'nl.msegers.project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

/Project/Services/build.gradle

```
group 'nl.msegers.project.services'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}
```

/Project/Services/MyService/build.gradle

```
group 'nl.msegers.project.services.myservice'
version parent.version

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'Navigation'
    version =  parent.version
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been scouring the web for an hour or so to get a structure like this working. In the meanwhile I've rebuild my project from scratch as well (Though I did not have much code anyway).

My code currently allows simple Spring boot sub projects without too much redundant configuration, and they can pretty easily compile the Libraries project, however this can use some work.

What I've got now is a structure like this.

/Project
/Project/Libraries
/Project/Libraries/Models
/Project/Services/
/Project/Services/Service

With the only notable build.gradle files (others are nearly empty):

/Project/Services/

```
group 'nl.msegers.project.services'
version parent.version

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "1.5.2.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

subprojects {
    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = "1.5.2.RELEASE"
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'


    dependencies {

        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
            exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        }
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

        compile project(':Libraries:Models')

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '3.1'
    }
}
```

/Project/Services/MyService

```
group 'nl.msegers.project.services.myservice'
version parent.version

jar {
    baseName = 'myservice'
    version =  parent.version
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have every project to inherit the dependencies from the root, you could use the [allprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:allprojects(groovy.lang.Closure)) script block on your root project like:

```
allprojects {
            dependencies {
        compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.+'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also work for sub projects?

Though my problem is that dependencies are not even loading when define in my build.gradle at the same level.

Comment: This issue is because you have defined a buildscript in one place for springboot, and apply the plugin in a different place, see: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript

Comment: Whilst your answer puts me in the right direction maybe. I did solve it slightly differently. Also having an /Libraries/Modules project which I included in my Services. I'll create a separate answer with what I've done somewhere today.